# Looking for Windows Hosting Reseller provider with decent reputation

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, reseller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for a windows web hosting reseller provider with the following requirements:

- Plesk control panel (for reseller and customers)
- Support for Magento, Joomla, and Wordpress
- A decent reputuation

I'd prefer to not go the VPS route because I do not want to support the server.

Answer (score 0):

I can't hep you with specific answers as my current reseller is Linux and uses CPanel/WHMCS (love it)and my previous one, which, while was running on Windows, used Helm which is out of date and lacks in features.

What I would suggest is visiting [WebHostingTalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/) as there is a whole section on there dedicated to resellers and you should be able to either find the info you need via a search or if you post a question you will very rapidly get a lot of feedback and certain names will "float to the top" helping you make your decision.

Good luck.

[Direct link to the Reseller section](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?s=fa18c2bfba2e126e7e8d7068b45b6c6c&f=3)